# Error when debugging .NET 6 project in Visual Studio on MacOS with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm encountering an issue while debugging my .NET 6 project in Visual Studio on MacOS. The project uses Entity Framework Core, and the following line of code is causing an error only when debugging in Visual Studio:

```
options.UseEF<SQLServerDb>(db => db.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Piranha")));
```

This code works perfectly fine when I debug the project in Visual Studio Code or JetBrains Rider. However, in Visual Studio, it raises an error. The error message is not very informative, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause of the issue.

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." ---> System.TypeInitializationException: "The type initializer for 'Piranha.Data.EF.Module' threw an exception." ---> System.ArgumentException: "GenericArguments[0], 'Piranha.Data.Media', on 'T MaxInteger[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T])' violates the constraint of type 'T'." ---> System.Security.VerificationException: "Method System.Linq.Enumerable.MaxInteger: type argument 'Piranha.Data.Media' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'."
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any insights into what might be causing this problem specifically in Visual Studio on MacOS?